# SQL Server select min date from 3 columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a table with several date fields. I need to get a derived field that is the oldest date of 3 particular fields. I have to do this for 4 different date sets.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One simple way is to use a `case` expressions:

```
select case when Date1 > Date2 and Date1 > Date3 then
           Date1 
       when Date2 > Date3 and Date2 > Date1 then
           Date2
       else
           Date3
       end As TheDate
from tableName
```

Though this is quite simple, it tends to get really cumbersome really fast, if you have more columns. Another option would be to use the `values` clause, like this:

```
select (
    select max(date)
    from (values (date1), (date2), (date3))v(date)
) 
from tableName
```

This also enables you to get min value easily.

Comment: You have to add something on the ELSE for Date 2 vs Date 3

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza corrected.

Comment: Well you change it, did you saw a problem with the previous one?

Comment: You cant have multiple else in a CASE. Check my edit

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza Yeah, I've noticed the typo. thanks for the fix but I was just editing in the other option :-)

Comment: I know dont worry, that is why I let you know in case you still were editing

Comment: Oooo.  I like the last one!  Never saw the values clause.  Will try in the morning and report back.

Comment: [Table Value Constructor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/table-value-constructor-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)

Comment: I had some trouble with the syntax btu got it to work from an example in the other thread marked as a dup.  SELECT [Other Fields],
  (SELECT Max(v) 
   FROM (VALUES (date1), (date2), (date3),...) AS value(v)) as [MaxDate]
FROM [YourTableName]

Comment: If Date2 or Date3 as NULL though this won't work.  I got round this by using OR instead of AND.